# Should we have a permanent "recommendations" chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-event

We used to have [**scheduled** recommendation chats](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/periodic-recommendation-chats).

That [didn't seem to work](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/822/is-the-recommendation-chat-still-alive) and was stopped.

IMHO, it may have been due to the scheduled aspect. Many people LOVE to ask for and provide recommendations (as witnessed by many questions asking for recommendations - AND many people posting a constructive comment about coming to SFF chat to get them). But based on old meta discussions, not too many people showed up for scheduled ones (<10).

> ***Question:*** *Does it make sense for us to institute a **permanent**, **non-scheduled** recommendation chat room separate from Mos Eisley?*

We would need a recommended protocol to deal with asynchronicity (e.g. a way to easily thread things), since chat doesn't have Q&A format; but IMHO the content win would be greater than formatting and navigational worries.

Answer (score 4):

[A long time ago](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/822/is-the-recommendation-chat-still-alive/824#824), I proposed the [SF topic of the day](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1056/sf-topic-of-the-day) room. It never took off.

I'm not sure whether it's better to have a separate room or not. My idea was to have a room with enforced topicality for people who are only interested in recommendations and don't want to wade through the banter of the general room. The downside is that it's harder to reach momentum when the room looks idle most of the time.

The “topic of the day” format is more geared towards regulars than towards one-off participants. My idea in having an official topic was to kickstart content by forcing participants to pick a subject rather than get bored when nobody's asking anything. It didn't work, so by all means let's try other formulas.

Comment: How do we go about "let's try" logictics? Do the mods have to create a permanent chat room?

Comment: @DVK What do you mean by “permanent chatroom”? The only things you might need a mod for are to unfreeze the old room if you want to reuse it (but I've already done it), or to advertise the room or an event or this meta post in the community bulletin.

Comment: My assumption was that any active room is deleted from the list if not used for a while, based on other rooms I saw disappear from the list

Comment: @DVK Hmmm, it might have been removed from the list because it was frozen. I've been a mod on chat for almost as long as I've been participating there, so I'm not sure what non-mods see. If you're thinking of one-to-one rooms, they tend to be deleted because rooms without a minimum number of posts by different users are automatically deleted if they're idle for too long, but that topic of the day room had passed the threshold. In any case, if a room is used actively, it won't be frozen or deleted (IIRC one post in a fortnight keeps a room alive).

Comment: I also don't see any other ones (e.g. moderator interview chats).

Comment: All other chatrooms associated with this site are frozen. Click the “show frozen rooms” button. (I just tried in incognito mode.)