# I'd love to know whether

Tags: discussion, chat-event

OK, this is just one example, but I want to know about the general case.

> What would cross-universe dragons be like? e.g. the dragons of the world of Harry Potter and the dragons of Anne McCaffrey's Dragons of Pern.

I can't see how this could be a good question on the main site, but I've love to see it discussed.  Would it be suitable as a chat room event theme, as a possible way to draw in new contributors?

Comment: Cross-universe questions are strictly off-topic; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/can-we-be-consistent-with-is-x-a-timelord-questions/2459#2459 you can always create your own chatroom and publicise it in the main chatroom but I don't think the question you're asking is likely to attract much attention.

Comment: As I understand this, the OP isn't proposing these types of questions for the main site (and explicitly states that), but rather suggesting themed chat events, [which have been discussed before](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/622/1359).

Comment: While the topic being asked doesn't personally interest me, I do think that this is a great question.  We do have a tendency to get inappropriate questions here, and having an outlet for them could well prove to help encourage new users (who may not fully understand how the site works yet) to stay and become good members of the main site.  Definite +1 from me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't see how this could be a good question on the main site

Agreed.

> Would it be suitable as a chat room event theme, as a possible way to draw in new contributors?

Sure!  This site used to have themed chat events, but interest and participation died out.

I believe it may have started with a regular [recommendation chat](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/457/1359), which is actually what started my participation here.

Unfortunately, that event [died](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/822/1359), and was replaced with a [topic of the day](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/824/1359) chat room.

Topic of the day died, too, so you might have some challenges getting such a chat to work, but it is certainly an appropriate use of the chat system.  All you need is [100 reputation to create new chat rooms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), so feel free to start the chat (although you might want to try and gauge interest in topics and organize the timing here on meta, first).

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback, and for the history of previous attempts at doing something similar.